# Assign a row to cell array in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, row, variable-assignment, cell-array

I am trying to do this as with matrices:

```
>> line_params{1,:} = {numberPatterns{i}, lw, iw};
The right hand side of this assignment has too few values to satisfy the left hand side.
```

but getting error above.

Types are following:

```
>> class(line_params)
ans =
cell

>> size(line_params)
ans =
    21     3

>> a={numberPatterns{i}, lw, iw};

>> class(a)
ans =
cell

>> size(a)
ans =
     1     3
```

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
line_params{1,:} = {numberPatterns{i}, lw, iw}
```

into

```
line_params(1,:) = {numberPatterns{i}, lw, iw}
```

(normal parenthesis).

If you use curly braces (`{}`), you reference the individual elements. That is,

```
line_params{1,:}
```

will return a comma-separated list of elements in the cell `line_params` in its first row. You cannot assign a cell array (single item) to a comma-separated list (multiple items).

If you use parenthesis (`()`), you reference the cell entry, i.e., a cell array will be returned. And you *can* assign a cell array (single item) to another cell array (single item) -- provided they have the same dimensions of course.